# How to create a wrapper class for particular method in C#

Tags: c#, wrapper

I need to create a wrapper for a class containing the below code.

```
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\Fillable.pdf");
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
PDField field = acroForm.getField("last");
field.setValue("c#");
pdfDoc.save("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\Fillable.pdf");
pdfDoc.close();
```

I have create two wrapper classes, but I am a bit confused regarding the next steps.

```
public class c_PDFdocu
{
    private PDDocument PD;

    public c_PDFdocu(string PDFPath)
    {
        PD = PDDocument.load(PDFPath);

    }
    public c_documentcatalog getDocumentCatalog()
    {

        return new c_documentcatalog(PD);
    }
}

public class c_documentcatalog
{
    private PDDocumentCatalog PDFDocCat;
    public c_documentcatalog(PDDocument PDFDoc)
    {
        PDFDocCat = PDFDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
    }

    public c_PDAcroForm getAcroForm()
    {
        return new c_PDAcroForm(PDFDocCat);
    }
}  


public class c_PDAcroForm
{
    private PDAcroForm acroForm;
    public c_PDAcroForm(PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog)
    {
        acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    }
}
```

How can I create a wrapper class for the remaining statements?

I need to pass the value into `getField`. It's user perspective is similar to setvalue. It falls under the same variable name `field`.

Thanks

Comment: remaining statemnts :  PDField field = acroForm.getField("last");
            field.setValue("c#");

Comment: Could you format your code properly please?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is essentially create a 'Facade'. A Facade (or wrapper) is essentially some code that takes difficult, finicky code and makes it easier to use.

In your situation, it makes more sense to make a class where the constructor takes the information that you need (such as the **path**) and then creates does all the difficult work inside of the class itself. For example:

```
class PDFdoc
{
   String path;
   PDDocument pdfDoc;
   PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog; 
   PDAcroForm acroForm; 
   PDField field;

   public PDFdoc(String path)
   {
      this.path = path;
      this.pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(path);
      this.docCatalog = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
      this.acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
      this.field = acroForm.getField("last");

      this.field.setValue("c#");
   }

   public Save()
   {
      this.pdfDoc.save(path);
   }

   public Close()
   {
      this.pdfDoc.close();
   }
}
```

Now when you want to save, just call `PDFdoc.Save` and `PDFDoc.close` and it will take care of all the work for you. The point is that a Facade *hides all of the difficult details about how a class works by encapsulating ("wrapping") it in another class with a much easier to use interface*.

Comment: actual purpose for creating it as wrapper class, need to convert it to com dll